# Editing answers does not give reputation anymore

Tags: discussion, editing

I noticed that when you have below $2000$ points you get $2$ reputation for editing a question, but once you reach $2000$ points where your edits don't have to revieved anymore you stop to get those $2$ points. I asked myself if there was any reason for this, why would you punish people with many points?

Comment: With enough negative votes, you will get below 2000 and then you can enjoy the extra reputation points again ;-)

Comment: @Fabian: the posts on meta don't generate reputation... :-)

Comment: edit tag wiki's instead...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't know why you would call this a "punishment." It makes sense for new users to have more avenues for increasing their reputation, since they need to in order to get more privileges and make a bigger contribution to the site. And if users above 2000 rep could get reputation for editing *without* overview, what's to stop them from constantly editing the same question over and over again to get reputation in a completely pointless way?

The act that merits +2 reputation is not the edit but the *approval* of the edit. That counts as a vote of confidence in the user.