# Why community user doesn't have a badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, community-user

As everyone of us using the site get badges when we complete a task like editing posts, raising flags, voting on questions and answers etc. Then why [this user don't have any badges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity)

Comment: It seems that community user earned badges at least on some sites. Meta.SE: [Community user badges on Sound Design and MathOverflow are not hidden like on all other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272173).

Comment: Do you also puzzle over the Community Users's lack of reputation?

Comment: @hardmath: Well, it never posted anything...

Comment: @Asaf: While there is [some modesty about Community's Questions and Answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), this user has been a prolific Editor (despite being last seen in 2010).  This could earn up to $2000$ reputation, [but you already knew that](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/editing-answers-does-not-give-reputation-anymore).

Comment: @hardmath In fact, the maximum is [1000 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82020).